# Strange visual issue while making android buttons the same width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a "Back" and a "Home" button that I am trying to align with the top right of the screen. I would like both buttons to be the same size but still `wrap_content` so that they are not taking up extra space. The following layout almost works except that the home button is slightly messed up and it is the slightest bit smaller than the back button.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

If I change the second LinearLayout to `fill_parent`, the buttons become even widths and are aligned perfectly, but they take up way too much space and become very wide.

Screenshot:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24225416/Images/back_home_buttons.jpg]

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"                        
                    android:text="Home" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Back" />

        </LinearLayout>                       

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is the M is wider than the C. Try using "###dp" as your button width, changing ### until the home one fits on one line and use that figure for both.

Comment: If I do this, will the text be guaranteed to fit in the button for smaller or larger screens?

Comment: dp is density independent pixels, it should self-adjust according to screen size.

Comment: well in this case the the font-size also matters. To be able to render layout correctly on devices with different font-size preferences set, you should use sp unit to specify the font-size and the button width as well.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the width you picked is not enough to fit the text of the first button. The text then gets wrapped over two lines. This in turn causes the default baseline alignment mechanism to shift the first button down. To achieve what you want, add the attribute measureWithLargestChild to LinearLayout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"                        
                android:text="Home" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Back" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This sounds like it will work, but it is giving me the following error message:  "No resource identifier found for attribute 'measureWithLargestChild' in package 'android'"  Any ideas how to fix this? Examples online don't seem to have anything that my layouts do not.

Comment: This attribute was added in API level 11 (Android 3.0.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The reason for that is, that the default value of [`baselineAligned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3abaselineAligned) is `true`, so the button is moved down to have the text on the same base line. Setting the value on the `LinearLayout` to `false` sloves the problem. Try to add this attribute to your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```